# I would like to hide my current image & replace it with a text in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As the title states, I'm trying to add a text that is only visible in Mobile View. The text will be a replacement to my logo. I'm using this code:

**CSS:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  header .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  header .logo a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  header .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  header .logo a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  header .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  header .logo a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
  header .logo {
    display: none;
  }
  header .logo a {
    display: none;
  }
}

.mobileShow {
  display: none;
}


/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 600px) and (max-device-width: 400px) {
  .mobileShow {
    display: inline-block;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo animated bounce">
      <a>Game Ware</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobileShow">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">GAME WARE</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

**This is the mobile view of the site:** http://mobt.me/Zgly

**This is the normal view of the site:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoAQm.jpg

As you can see, the mobile-only text "Game Ware" is not visible. But the mobile-only text is visible in Normal View. I want it to be visible only in Mobile View and hidden in normal view.

Help is appreciated! What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the class hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg provided by bootstrap to hide tags based on the screen resolution to hide content according to small middle and large screens.

```
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="logo animated bounce hidden-sm hidden-xs">
             <a>Game Ware</a>
          </div>           
        <div class="mobileShow hidden-md hidden-lg">
             <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">GAME WARE</h1>
    </div>
</div>
   </header>
```

Comment: I want to hide the mobileShow text in normal view, it doesn't seem to do that :(

Comment: Add class: hidden-xs class to the  mobile text div

Answer (score 0):

```
<header class="main-header">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="logo animated bounce visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
             <a>Game Ware</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mobileShow visible-xs">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">GAME WARE</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```